# Adding multiple values to a textView - Android

Tags: android, textview, android-button

I'm currently trying to make a basic app that incorporates 4 toggle buttons and a textview.  The idea is simple:  When a button is pressed, the textview will show which buttons are currently being pressed.  This can include multiple buttons (such as if, for example 1, 3, and 4 were pressed).  Here's the code I've written for it:

TextView buttons;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttons = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

public void buttonPressed(View v){
    boolean check = ((ToggleButton)v).isChecked();

    int b1 = 1, b2 = 2, b3 = 3, b4 = 4;

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.toggleButton1:
        if(check){
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed: " + b1);
        }
        else{
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed:");
        }
        break;
    case R.id.toggleButton2:
        if(check){
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed: " + b2);
        }
        else{
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed:");
        }
        break;
    case R.id.toggleButton3:
        if(check){
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed: " + b3);
        }
        else{
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed:");
        }
        break;
    case R.id.toggleButton4:
        if(check){
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed: " + b4);
        }
        else{
            buttons.setText("Buttons pressed:");
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }



}
```

Unfortunately, every time I run this program, the textview is overwritten, and I can't get it to validate that multiple buttons are pressed.  All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your textview always show number of ON buttons, I think you can do this way :

Keep tracks of your buttons

```
private ToggleButton[] btns = new ToggleButton[4];
```

In onCreate():

```
btn[0] = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
btn[1] = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
btn[2] = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
btn[3] = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton4);
```

Then in your buttonPressed handler :

```
String text = "Buttons pressed: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (btn[i].isCheck()) {
        text += (i + 1) + ", ";
    }
}
buttons.setText(text);
```

Comment: I was writing this answer but you wrote it first. So +1 for you and i discarded mine.

Comment: Rather than declare each findViewById you could do something along the lines of looping through the children of the view which is holding the buttons, adding a handler to each in the process.

This would save you declaring an array, finding the views and creating a handler for each. Resulting in much tidier code :)

Comment: @JoeBirch : Thank Joe for your comment. In fact I thought about it, but I don't know if zklim has something else (some other ToggleButton). And plus, he wants exactly which buttons are checked, so I just suggest him this way, because the order of the buttons got by getViewById depend on the order they are declared in the layout file, so if they are not declared in order (1->2->3->4), it can result a wrong output.
So I just suggest him this way and he can refine it in which way he likes after.
But of courses your suggestion should be considered and appriciated. :-)

Comment: @Son-HuyTRAN: I tried your recommendation, but noticed a few things: 1)  When I set the ToggleButton Array to private, the program crashes as soon as I launch it (using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 for testing).  When I set it to public, that fixed it, and the buttons showed up.
2)  However, when I press any of the buttons, the program crashes.  I think your syntax is all correct, so I'm not sure what else could be happening (??).

Comment: @Son-HuyTRAN no problem, just a thought. He could also use 'instance of' to check if the child view is an instance of a toggle button - that'd work fine regardless of the order of the views!

Comment: Could you show up all the code of your activity pls ? Because it is weird and I don't have enough information to go through...

Comment: @Son-HuyTRAN: Nevermind, I figured it out: I hadn't matched my textView "buttons" by using findViewById.  Once I added that, the code worked GREAT.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [append()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) if you don't want to overwrite the text that is already there. So something like

```
public void buttonPressed(View v){
boolean check = ((ToggleButton)v).isChecked();

int b1 = 1, b2 = 2, b3 = 3, b4 = 4;

switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.toggleButton1:
    if(check){
        buttons.append("" + b1);
    }
    else{
        buttons.setText("Buttons pressed:");
    }
    break;
```

And you can just use `buttons.setText("Buttons pressed");` once in `onCreate()` then append everything to that.